# JetBrains Account connection error: Network is unreachable: connect

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

This Problem shows me when I try to logged in with my student's account.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looks as if you have custom proxy configuration set up in **Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy**. Please try removing/changing it - does it help?

If you can't access IDE settings, try resetting them by deleting/renaming the configuration directory: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory